# How to get notified when a directive's children compiled?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a directive which has a `transclude:"element"` property and perform like a `ng-repeat` directive. Now I have another directive working with this one. I need to get notified when the children template have finished compiling so I could get the compiled content instead of the template.

Here is an example code show how its work

```
<ul directive-A>
    <li my-repeat-directive-b="option in options">
        <a>
            <span>{{option.name}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when `my-repeat-directive-b` finish its tranclude and linking function. I can get a list of `<li>` but its children element are still templates. I want to know are there any method to let me know the when children have also finished its compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rendered content, then use $timeout. The rendering of the ng-repeat is only available after the render phase:

**directive-A:**

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
   $timeout(function() {
      // access rendered li here 
      var lis = element.find('li');
      ...
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This works. I still not sure if this method will always work regardless of how long the children content render will take.

Comment: It will. JS is not truly multi-threaded. $timeout ensures that it will be executed after the $digest cycle. This is more of a queuing mechanism more than it is a wait thing. When you call $timeout, it calls setTimeout behind the scenes.  Now if you are in the middle of executing a function (which you are - you're inside the link function), then the browser will wait until the execution block completes before executing the timeout function. It just so happens, that the render phase is executed in the same overall execution block as the link phase

Answer (score 1):

Anything you put in a `postLink` function will be executed after the element has been completely compiled and linked, including its children.

You can read about this process in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) or the many existing answers on SO.

In general, the linking functions are defined by you and returned from the `compile` function:

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
      }
}
```

Comment: But the fact is I'm doing some transclude operation just like `ng-repeat` this will dynamically change the `<li>` elements and their children. I don't know how to detect this change and wait for its finished. Maybe I need a another directive on `<li>` element?

Comment: @lordfriend whatever element is containing those elements will get its `postLink` function called after all of its contents are done compiling and linking. So do whatever you want there.

Comment: I try to add a directive on the `<li>` element and add  console.log(element.children()[0].innerHTML) in its `postLink` function. It's called several times exactly, but the printed log still a template string `<a>{{option.name}}</a>`.